# How do I install offline packages for R using visual studio

Tags: r

Installing the packages from the internet/cran is not feasible, but we are able to download the zip packages from CRAN.

I am not finding much in the way of offline R package installation specific for a Windows environment and Visual Studio 2017.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it from the R prompt by running something like:

```
install.packages("path/to/package_v1.0.0.zip", repos = NULL)
```

See `?install.packages`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

```
utils:::menuInstallLocal()
```

This will open a window to have you navigate to the zip file.